# Beginner - Convert Basic Report to Chart

Tags: reporting, report-chart

I am new to salesforce and am helping creating a salesforce page for a start-up.  I have gotten the site set up, however I am working on customizing the dashboard.  I have populated many "Reports" with data.  With those reports I have created a table from 5 different data points.  The "Add Chart" button is grayed out because I have no grouping for the chart.  I added a Report to the grouping which reflects "Baseline, Year 1, Year 2, Year 3, Year 4".  My report now looks like this:

[image: matrix view]

This information is set up correctly in the table, and I would like create a bar chart that reflects the data points.  However, the "Add Chart" feature only allows me to create a graph that is sorted by record count.  **ALL RECORD COUNTS = 1 IN THIS SITUATION**.  To clarify, the values for "Baseline" should be (100,200,200,150,150):

[image: chart2]

Please advise on how I can create the graph I am looking for.  Do I need to restructure the data?  Use a different grouping?  This is pro-bono for a friends start-up non-profit.  Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, Follow below steps:

1. Create **Report Formula** fields which want to plot against Y-axis.
2. Edit your chart and select **Plot additional values**.
3. select formula fields which you've created. This will add bars in your chart as per your requirement.

Once you're done then click on Ok. But remember this has limitation of **3 columns**. So at max you can have **4 bars** in your chart. In below example, matrix report is used to group data as per status and their respective count. Refer below snapshot of reference:

**Matrix Report**

[image]

**Bar Chart 1**
[image]

Comment: Great thats a good start.  the biggest problem is that I cannot change the "value" of the y-axis from record count.  Each bar shows up as 1 record count and so every bar looks exactly the same.

Comment: @objectivelyC The image is just for a reference. You can select data as per your requirement.

Comment: The drop down for "Y-Axis" and "Value" both only allow me to select "Record Count".

Comment: @objectivelyC Make sure you've Matrix Type Report. I forgot to mention in my answer. I just updated the answer.

Comment: I have changed my question to reflect your suggestions.  The problem is that each "Record Count" = 1 for all columns and so my graph is incorrect.  For baseline, the records should be (100,200,200,150,150).  Please refer to my new pictures and advise.  Thanks!

Comment: Do I need to restructure my data to achieve this?  How can I group the values I need?

Comment: @objectivelyC Yes you need to restructure your data. I just created 2 formulas for my report and added it in my report. I was able to see those fields on reports and certainly I was able to put it in chart as per your requirement. Refer the answer. The formula fields were created on report and not on object. You can find it on the left side from were you drag and drop the fields.

Comment: This answered my question.  I will work with the formulas to create my chart.  Thanks